# How to cyclically play video from one position to another using MediaElement in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video, mediaelement

I am using WPF mediaelement for playing video. What I need is to cyclically play a video form x position to y position. Is there any way to achieve this without using timer and polling Position property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to poll the position property, but you can set it to begin play at start position, start a timer and set the interval for the time difference.

```
TimeSpan startTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
TImeSpan endTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(55);
int timeDifference = endTime.TotalSeconds - startTime.TotalSeconds;

mediaElement.Position = startTime;

Timer t = new Timer() { Interval = timeDifference * 1000, AutoReset = true };
t.Tick += (sender, e) { mediaElement.Position = startTime };
t.Start();
```